# suspicious hidden files

Tags: android, macos

Here are some odd hidden files in my home directory:[image: Stuff possibly related to Android][image: Caches of dubious value]

`wine` is no surprise; I have used it in the past, and the date is old.

`youtube-dl`: **maybe** I used it on that date.

`fontconfig`: don't think so

But `.android` three days ago?  We do not own any android devices, nor does anyone who has visited us, except maybe a realtor who was here 1 July.  But he did not access our network, and even if he did, he shouldn't have been able to create anything on my MacBook Pro that was asleep at the time and delay it for six weeks!

**Any reason I shouldn't just delete this stuff?  What would `.android` be for if we don't use Android?**  (No Google apps here either)

Comment: The content indicated [USB debugging authorization for Android Debugging Bridge (ADB)](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#Enabling). Did someone try to debug their Android device before?

Comment: There has never been an Android device near this computer.  Possible exception was the realtor mentioned.  But that was before the date shown, and if his phone was android, he didn't take it out of a pocket.  And he didn't know this computer was in the other room asleep.

Comment: It's unclear since it's not shown here, but is the modified date for the files also the same as the modified date for the folder?

Comment: @AndrewT., that's a good point that I should have included, but can't now that I've deleted the directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete anything in your user account, and any software that was using that data will just behave as it would for a brand new user account.

And of course you have a backup to restore the files in case anything goes wrong.

So delete away!

Having said that, I'd actually be more inclined to leave stuff if it's just a few Kb.

I have a .fontconfig folder, which seems to contain some sort of caching data related to my installed fonts; though it dates from a decade ago.

Software often uses hidden .files at the user home level for temporary files (which may then not get tidied up); config files (particularly in Unixy or cross-platform software); or even authorisation credentials/licensing.

Answer (score 2):

re your `.android` folder. Some apps may have Google Analytics built into them, and use that folder to store preferences. Mine contains an `analytics.settings` JSON file, which indicates to whatever software is using it whether I've opted-in to analytics collection, I presume. I'm not too fussed about which app it is as long as I understand the intent of the file.

You could use `fs_usage` (run sudo) to filter for processes that touch the folder, while you start up various apps, maybe starting with whatever has been installed or updated recently.

Comment: The idea of some app collaborating with NSA's biggest competitor without telling me is rather galling.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a .android.zip file in my home directory. It is dated from 15 August 2022. This machine was new in April 2022. No Android devices have come anywhere near it.

I suspect the OP's .android folder was an unzipped .android.zip file.

Comment: This is struggling to qualify as an answer.  Can you expand on this file or where it could have possibly come from?